# Indesign PDF-export convert color and transparency blend space

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, transparency, color-spaces, ebook

I'm a bit at a loss with this.
I have an indesign file that is made for print purposes, but for the pdf-ebook we export it via other joboptions/settings with RGB as it's color destination applied.

But as I see it, the joboptions can't change the transparency blend space, so if transparencies are applied in a document, I get the warning that the transparency blend space doesn't match the color space.

Is there a way for the transparency blend space to convert aswell via joboptions? Or does it even need to?

Of course, I could just also change the transparency blend space manually each time. But since I am not the only one who exports these files and this is something that can be forgotten easily (Or even worse, the person saves the indd with the changed transparency setting and thus corrupts the later exported pdf that is sent to the printing company), this is not an option.

Will it change/corrupt the pdf's colors or can the warning maybe just be ignored? If it does change the colors, is there away to export the pdf with a destination for color and transparency blend space?